# Best estimator for the variance of the empirical median

Tags: references, asymptotics, median

Let $X_i$ be $n=2k+1$ IID continuous random variables with distribution function $F$ and quantile function $F^{-1}$.

Let $m$ be their empirical median. It is well known that:

- If the $X_i$ were uniform on the $[0,1]$ interval, then $m$ would have a beta $\beta(k,k)$ distribution.
- The median of uniform variables is thus asymptotically Gaussian with variance $var(m) = k/8 \approx n/4$.
- If the $X_i$ are not uniform, then the median is instead a transformed version of the  $\beta(k,k)$ using the quantile function:

$$ m = F^{-1}( \beta_{k,k} ) $$

- Using the delta method, the median is thus generally asymptotically Gaussian with variance $ var(m) = n/4 f(m_0)^2 $ where $ f(m_0) $ is the density at the true median of the distribution $F$.

Thus, when we have complete knowledge of the underlying distribution, it is quite easy to characterize the distribution of $m$.

My question concerns the statistical problem of estimating $ var(m) $ in the absence of such knowledge. Is there an accepted best method or at least papers trying to tackle this issue?

Comment: Some published papers:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2286545.pdf,  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00949650108812071,

Comment: Thanks for the refs. Price and Bonett https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00949650108812071 offer a great review of six different options, though they don't commit very hard to an answer. It's interesting that all estimators of the variance that they present are handcrafted.

Comment: If you had the time to review the papers, maybe now you can answer your question yourself!